# How to get parameters from an inline onclick event with javascript, in order to use them inside a JS file

Tags: javascript, html

I have an inline on click event that looks like this:

```
<a href="#" class="nextStep" onclick="formHandler.changeStep(2, 'nameYourReport'); return false;">
```

This onclick basically slide the form to the next step, which works great. My issue is I also want to slide the form if the user clicks the enter key and I am having issues getting the proper parameters for my changeStep function within my actual JS component file since they are normally pulled in based on hardcoded values in the actual HTML.

So my question is, is there a way I can just pull or run the exact function on and enter keydown from an external js file.

My idea would to be to grab the fieldset(parent) with the class active. Then grab the a tag with the class of 'nextStep'. then run the function attached to that element.

So I have gotten the function from the HTML and now have is as a varible with this:

```
var parent = document.querySelectorAll('.fieldsetParent.active')[0],
    clickable  = parent.getElementsByClassName("nextStep")[0],
    changeStep = clickable.getAttribute('onClick')
         .replace('formHandler.', '')
         .replace(' return false;', '');
```

But when I call the variable which should output the function and theoretically run the function it equals to, it doesnt run.

Comment: How do you expect anyone to know unless you show the code to: `changeStep()`, or the rest of the page, the code the parameters come from, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `addEventListener` in JavaScript *instead* of inline `onclick` in HTML. Example:

```
clickable.addEventListener('click', function () {
  event.preventDefault()
  formHandler.changeStep(2, 'nameYourReport')
})
```

This way, you can call `formHandler.changeStep()` elsewhere if you need to.

```
document.addEventListener('keypress', function (ev) {
  if (ev.key === "Enter") {
    event.preventDefault()
    formHandler.changeStep(2, 'nameYourReport')
  }
})
```

You can't simply pull the function from the HTML because the attributes are strings not live code.

Comment: thanks for the input. 9 times out of 10 i will use addEventListeners. But this one time I am trying inline onClicks just because It would be nice to just apply the attribute where ever I want in the html. Also I am going to start using React so this is a little more like how react would do it..... But yes, i would say addEvertListeners would have been a little nicer